# Semi-Riemannian Metric and Curvature Tensor analytic at a point?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, analytic-functions

Because I am interested how to extend results with anayltic continuation on manifolds, I am reading  [Affine Osserman connections and their
Riemann extensions*](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0926224599000297). In theorem 12 they say in the first sentence that at each point $p\in M$, where $(M,g)$ is a semi-Riemannian manifold, the metric and the curvature tensor $\mathcal{R}$ are analytic functions. And I'm not able to justify this statement for myself.
Here are my thoughts:

A function on a manifold is analytic at a point if it is an analytic function with respect to every chart $(U,\varphi)$ around $p\in M$. I hope this is the right way to talk about analyticity on a manifold.

Now I wanted to look at the metric in a fixed chart as a polynomial, namely
$$g(\cdot)=\sum_{i,j=1}^n g_{ij}(\cdot) dx^i(\cdot)\otimes dx^j(\cdot).$$
So, I look at $g$ as a polynomial function that gives me for every point the inner product on the tangent spcae and in the same way I can look at $\mathcal{R}$ as a polynomial in the components of the metric and it's derivatives up to order 2.

Now I would argue that polynomials are analytic and therefore $g$ and $\mathcal{R}$ are anayltic at every $p\in M$.

I am sure that I overlook something. For example do I have to be concerned about the $dx^i\otimes dx^j$? Or what happens if I change the charts? Since the transition functions are not analytic in general do I need to assume a real-analytic structure or is this not necessary?

Comment: based on a cursory reading, I think they’re literally talking about the metric and curvature as multilinear maps on the tangent spaces, since they’re fixing the point $p\in M$. Since $g_p$ and $R_p$ are multilinear maps, they’re of course analytic functions (on the vector space $T_pM$). i.e if $V,W$ are real vector spaces, and $S:V^n\to W$ is an $n$-multilinear map, then it will be real-analytic (because even better: when you pick a basis and write things out, you’ll get a polynomial, because well… you started off with something multilinear). So, charts and stuff are completely irrelevant.